# Cannot get obj property to show up on html page when called (from json php file) in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Cant quite get it to the next level, please help!
I am trying to get the temperature to print out as well right below the description on the html page using DOM and ajax which is pulling the data from a php file which storing it json format. 
Not sure where the mistake is or if I am missing something.  I know I made a mistake because I can do a console.log and see the data but cant figure out how to just get the "temp" and its property to html.Any help or pointers is much appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!

```
 -----------html-------------------
<body>
<h1 class="title">Todays Weather Forecast</h1>
<p class="sub">Click the button the check the local weather.</p>

<button class="demo-centered" type="button" onclick="loadPhp()">Check Weather</button><br><br>
<div id="content"></p>
<div id="content2"></p>
</body>
---------------javascript file ---------------------------------------------
function loadPhp() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
if (xhr.status === 200) {
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  var newContent = '';
  var newContent2 = '';


  for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.weather.length; i++) {
    newContent += responseObject.weather[i].description;
  }

  for (var x in responseObject.main){
    console.log(x + ':' +responseObject.main[x]);
  }

  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Description: " + newContent;
  document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "Temperature: " +response.Object.main[x];
   }
  };

  xhr.open('GET', 'demo.php', true);
  xhr.send(null);

 }
}
----------------PHP file---------------------
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -116.8,
    "lat": 33.03
},
"weather": [{
    "id": 802,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "scattered clouds",
    "icon": "03d"
}],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 293.73,
    "feels_like": 289.89,
    "temp_min": 289.26,
    "temp_max": 295.93,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 52
},
"visibility": 16093,
"wind": {
    "speed": 5.7,
    "deg": 260
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 40
},
"dt": 1589408840,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5686,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1589374130,
    "sunset": 1589423903
},
"timezone": -25200,
"id": 5391832,
"name": "San Diego County",
"cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your code first is there is typo near `response.Object.main[x]..` this should be `responseObject.main[x]` .Also you have not close your `</div>` you have use `</p>` .

**Working Code** :

```js
var responseObject = {
  "coord": {
    "lon": -116.8,
    "lat": 33.03
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 802,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "scattered clouds",
    "icon": "03d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 293.73,
    "feels_like": 289.89,
    "temp_min": 289.26,
    "temp_max": 295.93,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 52
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.7,
    "deg": 260
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1589408840,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5686,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1589374130,
    "sunset": 1589423903
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
  "id": 5391832,
  "name": "San Diego County",
  "cod": 200
};
var newContent = '';
var newContent2 = '';


for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.weather.length; i++) {
  newContent += responseObject.weather[i].description;
}

for (var x in responseObject.main) {
  //console.log(x + ':' + responseObject.main[x]);
}

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Description: " + newContent;
document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = "Temperature: " + responseObject.main[x];//change here
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div> <!--close div-->
<div id="content2">
</div> <!--close div-->
```

Comment: Man I must have been tired thanks man - spent 2 hours on that simple thing